# Can't Uninstall Screensaver from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, windows-screensaver

Two screensaver apps I downloaded and installed for my PC did not impress me after I tested them out as my new screensavers. I can't uninstall these two screensavers. I searched online but couldn't find the answer.
Do you have any suggestions for how to remove screensavers from a PC running Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try uninstall from control panel

open control panel -> select uninstall a program -> select your application what you want to uninstall -> click uninstall

and iam recommended you to using [lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html)

Comment: Hey, Thanks :D,

I thought if the application isn't showing up in the apps list at the start then it'll not be showing up in uninstall a program in the control panel but I was wrong.

Thank you again :)